# Angular Jest Error "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm updated my nx angular workspace from 14 to 16, everything went well except the unit test part. I'm facing the following error when I'm running the test.

[image]